# Git merge --theirs ALL files EXCEPT the ones that have been edited by <name>, <name>, or <name>, in which case I'll fix merge conflicts myself?

Tags: git, merge, squash, mergetool

I have two branches, master and upstream, with thousands of files to merge and an equal number of merge conflicts.

Thing is, 90% of the upstream ("theirs") files are the ones I want to keep. Rather than "git mergetool"ing all of them, is there a way to automatically use all of the upstream files, UNLESS the file has been edited by specific people? That way, I can work out the merge conflicts manually myself with only a dozen or so files.

Here's how the pseudo code could work, in my mind:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream --squash --all-of-theirs-except firstguy@mail.com secondguy@mail.com
git mergetool //For the remaining conflicts
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do `git mergetool`, you can checkout the files from the upstream.  Then you can use `git mergetool` to resolve the conflicts for the rest of the files.

```
git merge upstream squash
git checkout upstream -- <files that you want as "theirs">
git mergetool //Resolve the remaining conflicts.
```

To get the list of files, you can use `git log --author=<email> --name-only --oneline` and parse the output to get list.  Or you can do `git checkout -- path/to/a/directory/` to checkout all the files from a specific directory without having to specifying all the files individually.

Comment: I like this idea, but there are still several thousand files that I'd have to go through. Could I use wildcards for certain folders and make it recursive?